Makefile change output hex file name using #define from header file
I use a #define inside a header file for firmware version. Can the makefile append the version number from the #define to the name of the hex file? Im using Atmel Studio on Windows. I was able to use a custom makefile in the project but dont know how to modify it for this task.

Maybe you create the define externally as well and pass it along to the source with compiler option -D, if that's an option?

Please clarify what is meant by "output hex file". 'Make' is typically used to run compilers and linkers that build executable files from source code. How does "output hex file" fit into this usage?

Maybe "hex file" is something standard on that Atmel Studio platform? Something that any makefile is supposed to build? If I guessed incorrectly, then what is it?

Atmel Studio is an IDE for writing micro controller firmware. The build outputs hex and binary files that flash the micro controller instead of executable.

Simple way would be using grep alternative for windows (something like findstr) in makefile. Than split and use version however you prefer.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Is there example of this in a makefile? Im new on modifying makefiles

I don't have example specific for findstr but you can use any makefile tutorial out there. It will teach you have to call a function from makefile. After that apply that knowledge the manual for using finstr in accessible through the link.
For piece of mind you can also call findstr from cmd and figure exact output that way.

I agree with the existing answer — find the #define code in the header file and extract the information you need from that line of code.
However, this relies on specific syntax you use for the version. If you ever change that syntax, extracting the version will fail. Also, if you ever add another line of code which looks similar, it may fail too.
If you want something more reliable, use the following idea. Create a C source file like this:
#include "version.h"
VERSION

Then run the C preprocessor on it. It doesn't matter that the code is invalid — you don't compile it, only preprocess. Then get the last line of the preprocessor's output.

Please read the last line of the OP's post. This suggests the OP does not yet have the skills/knowledge to access & modify the build script. Suggesting "only run the preprocessor" without specific directions is likely not going to help the OP. And, if/when the build starts "halting on error", the OP will be even more desperate for solutions. AND, there's a far simpler solution to what appears to be the OP's objective that entails flipping what is stored and defined where... Right now, one can only guess what "hex file" means to the OP... Jus' sayin'...
